# Send mail using php and Xampp not working

Tags: php, apache, email, gmail

I have tried to send a mail using php and sendmail. It looks simple but my configuration seems not to working.

**My sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

auth_username= my-address@gmail.com
auth_password= ***** (my pwd)
```

**Part of my php.ini**

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

**My simple php**

```
mail('xxxx@xxx.com', 'test msg', 'best messages', 'From:xxx@xxxx.com');
```

I don't receive anything in my mailbox. I also checked my spam folder.
After my configurations in sendmail and php.ini files, I restarted the Xampp Apache but nothing change.

I also tried port:25 or 465 or 587

Do I make errors ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should check sendmails log files to see what is going on. Typically that is something like `/var/log/maillog`. I see that you are on an MS-Windows platform where networking things are always strange, so you will have to dig around a bit for the location of that log file.

Comment: I got this message in my xampp/sendmail/errors file : Connection Closed Gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

by any chance do you want to use a third party mailer? Like php mailer?
Here [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
. I am using this whenever I'm on my development stage where I need to send mails and when I'm on live server I switch back to php mail function wherein it's already configured unlike when you are in your local machine. Hope that one helps.